# Live Stream Recording in Android

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, ffmpeg

I am trying to record a live stream of IPTV but couldn't find any solution.
Up and till now I have found it can be done through FFmpeg but this also not working for me.
Also, I am unaware of from this lib. command.
Does anyone have any better solution or can show me a way to record online live HTTP's recording.

Comment: Your question is unclear, more data is needed: what kind of stream, location, preferably example, like https://stream.foo.com:8000..., codec info, etc. FFmpeg can do that, I've seen it with ffmpeg lib in c# and bash scripts and ffmpeg binary.

Comment: Streams can be anything that can be played using an internet connection...
Although I managed to get a live stream recording through this command using FFmpeg, but if I am watching video while recording then FFmpeg records 30-sec video already when I am still looking at the 10-sec video.
And it's a live video you can say it's tv channel.
`ffmpeg -y -i http://.......m3u8 -c copy $filePath/MyOutput.mp4`

Comment: I didn't quite understand your problem. Are you saying that what you watch is behind what you record? Or vice versa? I tried this watching and recording and it is simultaneous (although it is webcam, not tv channel).  Here is my command:  ffmpeg -y -rtsp_transport tcp -i "rtsp://www.hessdalen.org:1935/rtplive/_definst_/hessdalen02.stream" -c copy -map 0 "/moje/filmovi/stream_test.mp4"  The stream is publicly available so you can test yourself.   The trick is to specify TCP stream, otherwise, ffmpeg tries UDP first and loses some 10 seconds there. But, then, your stream is perhaps UDP.